# division with a remainders (x86 assembly)

Tags: assembly, x86, division, tasm

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with the div bl instruction in this block of code? Im trying to divide 10/20 and the result should be 0.5. a(DB) and b(DB)

```
    mov al,  b; b==10
    mov bl,  a; a==20
    div bl ;
    mov bh, ah
```

Now i get 10 in ah, but the second problem is that i need to resolve (3*a-b/a) so

```
    mov ah,a; a=20
    mov al,3
    mul ah 
    mov cx,ax; cx=60

    mov al,b
    mov ah,0
    mov bl,a
    div bl
    mov bx, ax

    sub cx,bx
```

and it doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DIV is for integer division. 10/20 is 0, and the remainder is 10.

8-bit divide uses AH:AL (or AX) as the source register, placing the result in AL and the remainder in AH. (You seem to have left *AH* uninitialized).

*Fixed point* representation of 0.5 is possible with integer arithmetic by first multiplying the source '10' by number of fractions.

e.g.

```
 Base 10:
 10 * 1000  = 10,000 = "10000 / 1000"   = "ten"
 10000 / 20 =    500 = "  500 / 1000"   = "zero point five"

 Base 16:
 10 * 256 = 10 << 8 = 0x0A00 = 10*256 / 256 = "ten"
 0x0A00 / 20 =        0x0080 =    128 / 256 = "zero point five"
```

Answer (score 1):

First, `div bl` would divide `ax` contents and you only set `al`. The result will be `al` set to 0 (quotinent) and `ah` set to 10 (remainder). There's no way for result becoming `0.5` - integer division never yields non-integer results.